# Egyptian Arabic to IPA conversion?

Tags: ipa, arabic, transcription, online-resources

I am trying to transcript some text from Egyptian Arabic to IPA, but I can't seem to find an Egyptian Arabic dictionary with IPA transcription, an automatic transcriptor, or even comprehensive conversion tables online.

Is such a ressource available somewhere ?  A GNU/Linux compatible program would also do.

Comment: FWIW, here is the text I am trying to convert : "حِلْم القُطَط كُلُّه فِرَان".

Comment: And hopefully `[ħilm il-utˤatˤ kullu firaːn]` will not be too far from reality…

Comment: I think you got your hamzas in the wrong place.  'utat, not ut'at'.

Comment: @mobileink : Thanks.  How positive are you about this point ?  I guess it misses context, but Wikipedia consistently indicates `tˤ` for `ط` (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_Arabic).

Comment: my bad.  I misinterpreted the syms.  looks like you've got the right xlit for tta, but I was looking at the qaf.  in Egyptian arabic that should be a hamza.

Comment: let me add that "Egyl

Comment: how I hate this cell phone that keeps making me hit the wrong key!  "Egyptian Arabic" covers a lot of ground.  You probably mean Cairene Arabic, where qaf is pronounced like hamza (glottal stop).  But lots of Egyptians pronounce it like the g in got.

Comment: @mobileink Yes, I meant Cairene Arabic, since according to Wikipedia it's the most spoken Egyptian dialect.  [This book](https://archive.org/details/egyptianselftaug00thim) explains (p.9) your point, and indeed I read things like `[q]otat` in other dictionaries.  Would `[ħilm il-ʔutˤatˤ kullu firaːn]` fit better ?

Comment: that looks about right to me.  fyi most scholars (outside of linguists) do not use IPA for transliteration.  they're more likely to use something like http://referenceworks.brillonline.com/entries/encyclopaedia-islamica/system-of-transliteration-of-arabic-and-persian-characters-transliteration

Comment: Yes, I've learned it the hard way…  But for my project I need (even approximate) IPA.  Thanks.